# Hibernate complains about orphan removal for empty and untouched collection

Tags: hibernate, all-delete-orphan

**Update**: In the meantime, I opened an issue [HHH-15512](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15512) in the hibernate tracker.

I was recently forced to upgrade Hibernate from 5.x to 6.x and I am using the currently most recent version 6.1.2.Final.

Among the things that broke apart is that I have a parameterized test case that gets instantiated four times and doing something with a Entity. In only *two* of the four instances, committing the transaction results in the following error:

`A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance`

The relevant part of the entity is this:

```java
public class MyEntity {
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private final List<ChildOne> childOnes = new ArrayList<>();

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private final List<ChildTwo> childTwos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Of course it has many other attributes and collections, but the relevant part are two collections here.

The test case modifies *one* of them - `childOnes`. The hibernate exception complains about the *other* collection - `childTwos`. But that collection is never touched in the entire test case.

The test case goes like this (simplified):

```java
    @BeforeEach
    void openDatabaseSession() {
        dbTx = sfp.beginTransaction();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void closeDatabaseSession() {
        dbTx.commit();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("irrelevantSource")
    void doTest(/* some irrelevant params */) {
        final var child = new ChildOne();
        // given
        final var e = new MyEntity();
        e.addChildOne(child);
        sfp.getCurrentSession().save(e);

        // when
        final var result = service.someMethod(e); // not altering childTwos!

        // then
        final var testee = sfp.getCurrentSession().find(MyEntity.class, e.getId());
        assertNotNull(testee);
        var c = testee.getChildOnes();
        // ... some assertions ...
    }
```

I see that reloading the entity into a separate `testee` seems somehow redundant, but the error also occurs when I remove that and work with the original `e`.

I have already tried to debug the problem and found the following Hibernate code in Hibernate's Collections.java:

```
final EntityEntry e = persistenceContext.getEntry( owner );
//only collections belonging to deleted entities are allowed to be dereferenced in the case of orphan delete
if ( e != null && e.getStatus() != Status.DELETED && e.getStatus() != Status.GONE ) {
    throw new HibernateException(
            "A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: " +
                    loadedPersister.getRole()
    );
}
```

The debugger tells me that `e.getStatus() == Status.MANAGED`, which is obviously the root cause of the Exception.

But why is Hibernate even trying to perform orpahn removal on a completely untouched and never used collection? And why does Hibernate perform orphan removal on a collection that is apparently the child of a still managed entity?

And more interestingly: why does Hibernate only complain in two out of the four test case instances? They all do the same (at least regarding the collection Hibernate complains about).

And what can be done to fix that? I am currently thinking about just removing `orphanRemoval=true` everywhere but I resist to believe, that this Hibernate feature is just broken and it would take huge effort to delete the orphans manually... So it's not a real option.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the "solution".

Hibernate obviously evolved a bit and is more and more JPA compliant. Therefore `save()` is deprecated and the suggestion is to use `persist()`. But that's only half the truth, because a `persist()` needs a `flush()` while `save()` always guaranteed that you can obtain a generated ID e.g. That is why you do not see a `flush()` in the above code.

But that's not the point.

The point is, that the service method in the test case used a HQL query in two out of the four cases to retrieve the entity `e`. One would assume that this is the same object and it really is! And obviously this all has nothing to do with orphan removal or the collection, Hibernate complains about. But Hibernate does seem to have a valid and consistent state after this query is executed.

So I assume that the query, that retrieves `e` does pollute the persistence context somehow and there is some messed up state regarding `e` that was previously saved via `save()`.

A `flush()` after `save()` "fixes" the problem, although I don't have a clue why and how and why it worked in previous Hibernate versions without the `flush()`...

So maybe, just maybe, it is a bug in hibernate. But maybe it's just that some semantic rules have become a bit stricter than they were in the past and it is desired behavior now and just worked accidentally in previous versions. Who knows...

Comment: Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov and how are the chances that this issue is not instantly rejected, because the code uses the deprecated save() method? I am sure I will find some time to do that in the next few days.

Comment: You don't need to flush to obtain an id, after `persist` returns, ids must be set on the objects. Calling `flush` explicitly also shouldn't be necessary, unless you messed with the flush mode configuration: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing

Comment: @ChristianBeikov how is that possible, if the ID is generated by auto_increment of the database? For this, the INSERT must have happened. Or maybe I am getting something fundamentally wrong. But we will see - I try to come up with the requested test case(es) soon. But I will need some free time for this.

Comment: In case of `@GeneratedValue(IDENTITY)`, Hibernate will issue the insert statement when calling `persist`.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov yes, indeed, I apologize, that's exactly what is documented in the linked documentation. Problems only arise, when the strategy for Id columns is not properly configured (e.g. using AUTO instead of IDENTITY despite the column being defined with auto_increment). That makes it even more interesting, why inserting a flush() actually solved the original problem. I will post the ticket number here, once I am confident to have a proper test case up and running.

Comment: If you use `AUTO` and that resolves to `SEQUENCE` internally, but on the database side the column uses `auto_increment`, then it might just *happen to work*, but doesn't really. Either way, that's an unsupported configuration. The schema must match the expectations of Hibernate.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I tried to come up with a test case, but unfortunately I am not able to do so. Your test case template is using JUnit 4 still and the bug only occurs within a parameterized test (JUnit 5). At least I could pin the bug down this way. Maybe it has something to do with the execution strategy of parameterized tests.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your test environment. You can use `@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")` and `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` in JUnit 4 to have a similar experience.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov no, that does not even work, because `buildSessionFactory()` is never called in that case and `sessionFactory` will be `null` during the entire test case.... I opened HHH-15512 with JUnit 5 test case now - only that can demonstrate the bug properly. I also opened HHH-15510 because that annoyed me as well. By the way, it's not so easy to write a simple test case to reproduce a bug, because Hibernate is always complaining about *something* that seems to work elsewhere, just because some irrelevant details are different. Very hard to use. Took me hours to come up with the tests.